Why is my full wave rectifier circuit not working?
I built the following full wave rectifier circuit. The negative waves should be flipped to positive waves but they are completely cut off. Why are the negative waves cutoff and are not flipped ?


Where are your voltage probes in the circuit?

You are plotting v(OUT) relative to ground and not to the lower end of R1: -

I've put a red circle around the node where you are incorrectly plotting v(OUT) relative to (should you expect to see the voltage across R1). That node has a GND symbol attached and, that means that a plot of v(OUT) does exactly that; it plots v(OUT) relative to GND.

Thank you. It works now. Also added a capacitor parallel to R1 and LTspice showed me an error with Matrix ... but then i grounded also the negative terminal of R1 and then it worked.

@TimGraf you can't ground both the input to the bridge rectifier and the output because you short out a diode. if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Your diodes are connected incorrectly. The cathodes of D1 and D3 should be connected together, and the anodes should be connected to the positive terminal of the input voltage. Similarly, the cathodes of D2 and D4 should be connected together, and the anodes should be connected to the negative terminal of the input voltage.

Your answer appears to have accumulated a couple of down-votes. Would you care to show us what you're suggesting by making use of the site's built-in schematic editor in case there's some confusion?

The rectifier is drawn correctly. Your suggestion doesn't seem to make sense: if you have two diodes D1 and D3, with cathodes shorted, then you also connect anodes to the same "terminal" of the input voltage, you just got two diodes in parallel. Besides, there is no positive nor negative terminal of the input voltage. That's the whole point of a rectifier.
